# Serve uploaded picture using symfony2

Tags: php, apache, symfony, assets

I'm building an API with symfony2 the problem is that I want to retrive the files uploaded to some directory and whenever I type de url in the browser, I get the following message:

```
{"status":{"code":0,"msg":"No route found for \"GET \/asdf.txt\""}}
```

Does anybody know why is this happening? Seems like apache is unable to serve the static files in this directory. The files are actually there, but are unable to be served through a url.

I'm using this controller to upload the file:

```
public function postAttachmentAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->files->get("attachment");

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $exam = $em->find("MyBundle\ApiBundle\Entity\TheEntity", $id);
        if (!$exam) throw new Exception("No stuff was found with given id", 404);

        foreach ($request->files as $uploadedFile) {

            $fileName = md5($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName() . microtime()) . "." . $uploadedFile->guessExtension();
            $file->move("uploads", $fileName);
            $exam->setAttachmentPath("/uploads/". $fileName);
        }

        return $this->getResponse(200, "/uploads/". $fileName);
    }
```

Comment: You have to type in browser webPath() of file (if it's entity). You should provide us some code of your controller, and entity if possible.

Comment: there is no entity nor controller, I just would like to get the file from the url via GET. Do I have to create a controller for this?

Comment: Well, when you upload file, first you have to capture request using controller. So yes, there have to be one. After you have to create action inside to save file inside app structure. More info in tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Comment: I've added the action which saves the files to the server

Comment: Does it solves your problem? If doesn't, give code.

Comment: Nope, that action was already there, I just added to the question. My problem is serving static files within the symfony project

Comment: Try url `/uploads/FILENAME`

Comment: thats how I get the error I posted No route found for "GET /uploads/asdf.txt

Comment: You posted in first post, that you get No route exception for `GET /asdf.txt`, not `GET /uploads/asdf.txt` - it matters. Please check if file was moved to right location, attach screen of file with file path.